# Change default Steam download folder from command line for all users

Tags: command-line, steam

I have a classroom of 35 Ubuntu computers managed by Puppet.  I want to install Steam on them... no prob here.

But student home drives are networked, and I don't want Steam downloading to their networked home drives by default.

Each computer has a 1 TB SSD, and a shared space at `/shared`.  This is where I want the default download location set to.

Is there a way for me to change Steam's default download folder via the command line, for all users of Steam?

Comment: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7418-YUBN-8129

Comment: You won't be able to change Steam settings by commandline, I don't think, but you could use symlinks, if that's acceptable to you. Furthermore, I'm not sure how Steam will deal with everyone sharing the same download folder...

Comment: I like the symlink idea... gonna think about that.